# FORTH Networking Question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, vote-to-undelete

I asked a question on the FORTH language, that question was closed. It now has what is otherwise a duplicate on it,

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602466/forth-networking-library?noredirect=1&lq=1
- [How to send a GET/POST request with Forth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132956/how-to-send-a-get-post-request-with-forth)

Can we reopen my question and get the other one close as a duplicate? The people closing these questions should have experience with the language. It's unfair that we have to be so vigilant in defending our questions against others that have never used the technology.

**FORTH as a language does not have a Networking Library.** It predates computer networking. How you interface with computers on a network by way of sockets in a language that predates networking seems to be totally on topic on this site.

Answer (score 7):

I get it - FORTH is a fairly niche language and this is a fairly niche subject, but I don't see much in the way of incentive to reopen this question.

The question itself is *technically* asking for a library, and while I don't disagree that in spite of it all, this is a fairly weak justification...I'm not seeing a strong enough justification to *reopen* the question, either.  A quick Google search does turn up some documentation (even if it looks like it's permanently stuck in the 90s) around networking in FORTH.  It's also the case that any other question which asked anything similar in a more modern language wouldn't  survive a thousandth as long as yours did.

Comment: Yes, so what's wrong with asking for a library? If the language itself does not have networking IO and you want to perform networking, *something* has to provide that feature if it's possible, and that something would be a library (or extension of the language). Being that the language predates networking, that seems like a popular question. Which is why despite having the question **deleted** an almost unheard of action for such question, it was reasked again by someone else merely a few months later. And, with a direct reference to my question.

Comment: What's wrong with asking for a library?  Besides that being *explicitly* called out as a reason for a question being off-topic...

Comment: @EvanCarroll asking for libraries just invites low quality one liner advertisement answers; you get what you ask for. The off-topic rules basically exist to guard against that happening, you're triggered to ask questions which invite better and more useful answers. Your main problem seems to be how to implement a HTTP client using Forth, a fair problem to have. So the question should be about that, there is no need to hammer on libraries. If there is a library you can be sure that a solution answer will naturally recommend one and show how to use it.